# Trying to get msgpack-cli to give me the same packed byte array as it does in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, serialization, msgpack

In JavaScript, I can use [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/index.html) to pack an object as follows:

```
msgpack.pack(payload);
```

Where payload is the following object:

```
var payload = { event: "phx_join", payload: {}, ref: "1", topic: "players:1" };
```

When I call `msgpack.pack(payload);` on this object, I get the following bytes back (as a `Uint8Array`):

```
[132, 165, 116, 111, 112, 105, 99, 169, 112, 108, 97, 121, 101, 114, 115, 58, 49, 165, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 168, 112, 104, 120, 95, 106, 111, 105, 110, 167, 112, 97, 121, 108, 111, 97, 100, 128, 163, 114, 101, 102, 161, 49]
```

How can I use [msgpack-cli](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli) in C# to convert an object from C# to the same byte sequence as above? The object format I am using in C# is not so important, what's important is that the byte sequence is the same. Here is what I've tried:

```
public class Payload
{
    public string @event;
    public MessagePackObject payload;
    public string @ref;
    public string topic;
}

var payload = new Payload
{
    @event = "phx_join",
    payload = new MessagePackObject(),
    @ref = "1",
    topic = "players:1"
};
var packedBytes = SerializationContext.Default.GetSerializer<Payload>().PackSingleObject(payload);
```

Unfortunately, the packed bytes I get back in this case are as follows:

```
[148, 168, 112, 104, 120, 95, 106, 111, 105, 110, 192, 161, 49, 169, 112, 108, 97, 121, 101, 114, 115, 58, 49]
```

It is not the same as the packed data I get from JavaScript. I thought message pack was supposed to be cross-platform friendly. What's going on here and how can I create a C# equivalent object to make the deserializer pack it to the same byte array as it does in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The trick is to check the first byte encoded in the JavaScript, and you will see that `132` corresponds to HEX `0x84`. HEX `0x84` according to the [message pack specification](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md) is a `fixmap` (`0x80` to `0x8f`). Using this hint, we can try to guess that a `fixmap` must correspond to a dictionary data type in C# (since a map is more or less like a dictionary of key-value pairs).

We just need to use a payload object that is actually a dictionary of `string` and `object` pairs, and [msgpack-cli](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli) will successfully pack it to the same byte sequence from C#:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    { "event", "phx_join" },
    { "payload", new Dictionary<string, object>() },
    { "ref", "1" },
    { "topic", "players:1" }
};
var packedBytes = SerializationContext.Default.GetSerializer<Dictionary<string, object>>().PackSingleObject(payload);
```